# Custom mass actions with dialog in OroCRM

Tags: widget, orocrm

I am making some customizations to OroCRM, in this case I need to do a massive action on several records, but when selecting the desired option a modal should appear to choose one of the possible owners of the system.

For that I included the following changes in the system:

- I included the mass-actions option in the datagrids:

```
            change_owner:
                type:            lead_change_owner_mass_edit
                handler:         pb_lead.mass_action.change_owner.handler
                acl_resource:    oro_sales_lead_update
                route:           pb_lead_datagrid_mass_action_change_owner
                label:           pb.lead.mass_actions.change_owner.label
                icon:            user
                data_identifier: lead.id
                frontend_options:
                    title:       "@translator->trans(pb.lead.mass_actions.change_owner.label)"
                    dialogOptions:
                        width: 500
                        modal: true
                        allowMaximize: false
                        allowMinimize: false
```

- I defined an associated action as shown:

```
class ChangeOwnerAction extends WindowMassAction
{
    /** @var array */
    protected $requiredOptions = ['handler', 'route', 'data_identifier'];

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setOptions(ActionConfiguration $options)
    {
        if (empty($options['frontend_type'])) {
            $options['frontend_type'] = 'edit-mass';
        }

        return parent::setOptions($options);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getAllowedRequestTypes()
    {
        return [Request::METHOD_POST];
    }
}
```

This action is defined as a service:

```
services:
    #Change owner windows action
    pb_lead.mass_action.type.changeownermass:
        class: PB\Bundle\LeadBundle\Datagrid\Extension\MassAction\Actions\Widget\ChangeOwnerAction
        shared: false
        tags:
            - { name: oro_datagrid.extension.mass_action.type, type: lead_change_owner_mass_edit }
```

Additionally, the controller that has a method with the route defined in the datagrid is included:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/change-owner-mass-edit-lead", name="pb_lead_datagrid_mass_action_change_owner")
     * @AclAncestor("oro_sales_lead_update")
     * @Template("@PBLead/Lead/widget/mass_change_owner_update.html.twig")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function massChangeOwnerAction(Request $request)
    {
        dump($request);

        $responseData = [
            'inset' => $request->get('inset', null),
            'values' => $request->get('values', null),
        ];
        ...
        
        return $responseData;
    }
```

This controller was defined as a service in controllers.yml:

```
    PB\Bundle\LeadBundle\Controller\Frontend\LeadChangeOwnerController:
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ['@Psr\Container\ContainerInterface']]
        tags:
            - { name: container.service_subscriber }
```

On the other hand, 2 classes were defined: an abstract and a handler that extends from it to manage the mass actions. Both handlers are defined as services:

```
    #Abstract Lead mass action handler
    pb_lead.abstract_lead_mass_action_handler:
        class: PB\Bundle\LeadBundle\Datagrid\Extension\MassAction\AbstractLeadMassActionHandler
        abstract: true
        arguments:
            - '@oro_entity.doctrine_helper'
            - '@oro_security.acl_helper'

    #Lead change owner mass action HANDLER
    pb_lead.mass_action.change_owner.handler:
        parent: pb_lead.abstract_lead_mass_action_handler
        public: true
        class: PB\Bundle\LeadBundle\Datagrid\Extension\MassActionxzczxcz\LeadChangeOwnerMassActionHandler
        calls:
            - ['setTranslator', ['@translator']]
            - ['setFormFactory', ['@form.factory']]
```

There is a custom form and a view that are called from the controller.

Form:

```
class LeadChangeOwnerMassType extends AbstractType
{
    const NAME = 'pb_lead_change_owner_mass_type';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'owner',
                UserAclSelectType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'pb.lead.mass_actions.change_owner.label',
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotNull()
                    ]
                ]
            );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Lead::class,
        ]);
    }
```

View:

```
{% extends '@OroAction/Operation/form.html.twig' %}
{% set formAction = path('pb_lead_datagrid_mass_action_change_owner', {gridName: 'sales-lead-grid', actionName: 'change_owner', inset: inset, values: values }) %}
{% block form %}
    <form id="{{ form.vars.id }}"
          name="{{ form.vars.name }}"
          action="{{ formAction }}"
          method="{{ form.vars.method }}"
          class="form-dialog"
    >
        <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
            {{ form_row(form) }}
        </fieldset>

        <div class="hidden">
            {{ form_rest(form) }}
        </div>

        <div class="widget-actions">
            <button class="btn" type="reset">{{ 'Cancel'|trans }}</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">{{ 'Apply'|trans }}</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    {{ oro_form_js_validation(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

The question is: Why is the modal not showing?

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is that the route must start with "oro_", only that a small detail does not allow to show modal.

```
            change_owner:
                type:            lead_change_owner_mass_edit
                handler:         pb_lead.mass_action.change_owner.handler
                acl_resource:    oro_sales_lead_update
                route:           oro_lead_mass_action_change_owner
                label:           pb.lead.mass_actions.change_owner.label
                icon:            user
                data_identifier: lead.id
                frontend_options:
                    title:       "@translator->trans(pb.lead.mass_actions.change_owner.label)"
                    dialogOptions:
                        width: 500
                        modal: true
                        allowMaximize: false
                        allowMinimize: false
```